# Cmake: Why INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES can be populated behind my back

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake library target. To specify where to look for headers, I do:

```
target_include_directories(target 
    PUBLIC 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:/some/absolute/directory> 
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
```

The problem is that the equivalent of `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` is added to the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property before `$<BUILD_INTERFACE:/some/absolute/directory>` behind my back, causing a

```
CMake Building issue: 
INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property contains path 
[ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ]
which is prefixed in the source directory
```

If I manually edit the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property to remove it, the error is gone.

This is probably because of something else somewhere in the project (it's a very big project) but I can't find what it is.

It is driving me crazy, any idea ?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR.html ?

Comment: @KamilCuk wouldn't that also include `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`?

Comment: you could try to grep your codebase and any external dependencies for `target_include_directories(target` or equivalent `set_property` or `set_target_properties`.

Comment: @KamilCuk We checked and it's OFF.

Comment: @starball This is what we did, but I didn't see anything suspicious.

Comment: what [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) are you using? Does this happen with other generators? Does this happen for all targets with that generator? Does it happen in a minimal project with a basically bare target?

Comment: @starball The generator is Visual Studio, it does not happen in a minimal project.

Comment: Does this happen with other generators? Does this happen for all targets with that generator?

Comment: @starball I can't test easily with another generator right now, but it does the same with other targets, the problem seems to be project wise.

Comment: Did you give `cmake <other options> --trace-expand` a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was the cause of the problem.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#whitespace-and-quoting

I was passing a variable containing an empty string to one of the generator expression. Like:

```
set(MY_PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIRS "" /some/absolute/dir)

target_include_directories(
    ${TARGET_NAME} 
    PUBLIC 
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${MY_PUBLIC_INCLUDE_DIRS}>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
```

Somehow, this result to add the current source dir prior to the generator expression in the resulting property.

The solution is to correctly quote the generator expressions.

Comment: Yeah, this is nasty. An empty string will get [interpreted as a relative path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html), which is what pulls the current source directory in. Furthermore, `target_include_directories` accepts an arbitrary number of relative or absolute paths as arguments, and your `set` call sets up a list of two paths.